# Что, если требуются не все данные для сущности?

Tags: php

К примеру есть сущность User (геттеры и сеттеры опустим):

```
class User
{
    private $id;
    private $email;
    private $phone;
    private $status;
    private $name;
    private $surname;
    private $avatar;
    private $visit_at;
```

Иногда сущности бывают весьма большие, а в конкретных случаях требуются ну скажем совсем не много данных. Например сущность User может иметь много свойств, включая профиль, реляции на права доступа и тп. Однако требоваться по сути может только ФИО или только часть данных.

От сюда нет смысла делать тяжелый запрос и наполнять сущность целиком только для того, чтобы вывести имя пользователя. Поэтому я могу сделать запрос вида:

```
SELECT id,name,surname FROM users ....
```

**Поэтому возникает вопрос: правильно ли заполнять сущность не целиком, а только необходимыми данными или нужно создавать такие себе мини сущности на все случаи жизнь ?**

Comment: Попахивает тут наследовагием. Human -> Account

Comment: наверное, любой нормальный _ORM_ фреймворк при выборке данных позволяет задавать какие связные сущности извлекать, и какие вообще поля извлекать. так что этот подход вполне нормален. А вот плодить миллион классов точно не имеет никакого смысла, особенно привязанных как одной и той же таблице.